# Is it possible to make pytest report if a function is never called directly in a test?

Tags: python, pytest, test-coverage, pytest-cov

### Example

```
def main(p):
    if foo_a(p):
        return False
    return p**2

def foo_a(p):
    return p % 11 == 0
```

Now you can get 100% test coverage by

```
import unittest
from script import main

class Foobar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        self.assertEquals(main(3), 9)
```

But maybe one wanted `foo_a` to be `p % 2 == 0` instead.

### The question

Branch coverage would shed a light on it, but I would also like to know if a function was never called "directly" by a test (such as `main` is in the example), but only indirectly (such as `foo_a` in the example).

Is this possible with pytest?

Comment: What's the purpose of "But maybe one wanted foo_a to be p % 2 == 0 instead." sentence?

Comment: I wanted to say that although the function foo_a has 100% line and branch coverage, it is actually not tested. The code is covered, but the values are not checked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just general line of thought is to unittest `foo_a` as well

```
import unittest
from script import main, foo_a

class Foobar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        self.assertEquals(main(3), 9)

    def test_foo_a(self):
        self.assertEquals(foo_a(11), True)
```

You are probably looking for https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1/ which can be used with pytest https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov/, this tool can show you exactly which lines of code had been called during testing

But I think there is another way to check your problem it is called mutation testing, here are some libraries that could help you with it

https://github.com/sixty-north/cosmic-ray

https://github.com/mutpy/mutpy

And also look into property based testing libraries like https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/tree/master/hypothesis-python